# Distance of a point from coordinate plane

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

my really basic question on linear algebra is confusing me: I want to find the distance of a point ( A (2 , 3, -1) ) from the coordinates planes ( x = 0 and y = 0 and z = 0 ). So, first thing I think, I can use the easy formula that finds the distance of a point from a plane... but it doesn't work!
So, second way: using pitagora, so, for example, for the z = 0 plane, make Pitagora of 2 and 3, that gives $\sqrt{13}$. Could it be correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you want to use is orthogonal projection of $A$ onto the corresponding plane.  That projection is a single point (call it $P$).  Now find the distance from $A$ to $P$.

Comment: Exactly what was the "easy formula that finds the distance of a point from a plane" that you tried to use?

Comment: (Modulus of (ax+by+cz+d)) / sqrt(a^2+b^2+c^2) is the easy formula I meant; anyway, to avs, is the point P you are reffering to P(2,3,0), considering the plane z = 0?

Comment: So, what are the coefficients in this formula for, say, the $x=0$ plane?